# Open jpeg with photoshop and just save it, do i loose quality?

Tags: photoshop

I apologize for what seems a stupid question, but I need to know...

If I open an image with Photoshop, let’s say a jpeg, and save the image without actually doing anything (open the image, click save and that’s all), and i do this over and over again, do I loose quality?
I believe it looses quality when i do changes and save it, but what about opening the image and just save it multiple times without applying any changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually yes, you do. That is because the quantization in JPEG isn't lossless and will reduce quality up to a fixed point after which no further degradation will occur (depending on the quality you saved at the result will be more or less visible).

*However*, there is a special case with Photoshop where quality degrades much faster because they tweaked the algorithm. Neal Kravetz of Hacker Factor has [an article about exactly that](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/355-How-I-Met-Your-Mother-Through-Photoshop.html):

> I resaved the image repeatedly at 99% quality. (Load, save at 99%, reload, resave at 99%, repeat.) At 99% quality, the changes stop after 11 resaves. (Since Q99 takes very tiny steps, it hits a local minima quickly.) Resaved files #11 through #500 all have the exact same sha1 checksum. At 75% quality, it stops after 54 resaves (saves #54 through #500 are identical).
>
> [...]
>
> I repeated the experiment manually, using Photoshop. I lost count around 12 (doing it manually and the phone rang) [...] With fewer than two dozen resaves, you can already see parts of the walls getting brighter and darker -- much more than the JPEG algorithm can account for.
>
> [...]
>
> Yes, repeatedly saving a JPEG makes the image worse. But repeatedly saving it with Photoshop makes it much worse.

Comment: so i does loose quality just by saving it without actually doing anything.. thanks for the link

Comment: It does, up to a point after which it does no longer.

Answer (score 1):

You will lose quality as Photoshop has a default JPEG save quality that is <100%.

Whenever you save an image as JPEG, it will process and compress the image, losing quality as JPEG is a lossy format.

Comment: Note that the JPEG compression will stop degrading the image further after a certain point. However, in Photoshop's case it won't. The quality level has nothing to do with that at all.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I had the (incorrect) assumption that when setting quality level to 100% would cause Photoshop to use a "lossless" quantization matrix.

Answer (score -3):

it would execute the same saving code for the same pixels as before, so, no.

Comment: so, it only takes one pixel change for the image (jpeg) to start loosing quality when i save it... interesting... does it apply for png images as well?

Comment: @Marco JPEG is a lossy format, you will lose quality. PNG is a lossless format so you will not lose quality.